Can I bring fish products from Indonesia to Germany?
I want to give my friend some foods like "sambal roa" that contains fish and "kentang mustofa". Is that legal in Germany and should she put it in her hand carry or luggage?

Yes, travellers to the EU can bring in up to 20 kilograms of fish products.  Cooked potato (kentang) products are also OK.
Your friend will definitely want to put the sambal in checked luggage.  If they bring it as carry-on, it will be considered a liquid/gel and confiscated if there is more than 100ml per container.  Pack it carefully, I once had a container of kimchi break in a checked-in backpack and it was quite messy!
